# What should be the logstash grok filter for this log4j log?

Tags: log4j, logstash, logstash-grok

I've been asked to consolidate our log4j log files (NOT using Socket calls for now) into a Logstash JSON file that I'll then feed to Elasticsearch. Our code use the RollingFileAppender. Here's an example log entry.

```
2016-04-22 16:43:25,172 ERROR :SomeUser : 2 [com.mycompany.SomeClass]  AttributeSchema 'Customer |Customer |Individual|Individual|Quarter|Date' : 17.203 The Log Message.
```

Here's the ConversionPattern value in our log4j.properties file

```
<param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %p %x %X{username}:%t [%c] %m %n" />
```

Can someone please help me write a Logstash Grok filter that will parse the line? I have the following so far

```
filter {
  if [type] == "log4j" {
    grok {
        match => ["message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logdate} %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} %{GREEDYDATA:messsage}"]
    }
    date {
        match => ["logdate", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS", "ISO8601"]
    }
  }
}
```

But of course it takes everything after the priority as the message. I want to further segregate AT LEAST the following fields (defined in [Log4j Pattern Layout](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_patternlayout.htm))

- User (%X{username})
- Classpath ([%c])
- Thread (%t)
- Nested Diagnostic Content (%x)
- Message itself (%m)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to make the following filter work.

```
filter {
    mutate {
      strip => "message"
    }
    grok {
      match => {
        "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logdate} %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} :%{DATA:thread} : %{NUMBER:thread_pool} \[(?<classname>[^\]]+)\] %{SPACE} %{GREEDYDATA:msgbody}"
      }
    }
    date {
      match => ["logdate", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS", "ISO8601"]
    }
}
```

However, this is specific to the above log.

I have a followup question. How can i "pad" the patterns to manage the "spaces" in each pattern. For example, an ERROR log level takes up 5 spaces, while an INFO log level takes up 4, so how do manage this so it works for both ERROR and INFO logs?

Comment: To answer my follow question, put a %{SPACE} or a \+s.